# Getting errors in nativescript drop down

Tags: nativescript-angular

Run time using this command:- tns run android --device Nexus_5X_API_27

Error:-

> ERROR in node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/drop-down.d.ts(16,33):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'data/observable-array'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/drop-down.d.ts(17,62): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'ui/core/view'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/drop-down.d.ts(18,30): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'ui/gestures/gestures'.
>   node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/drop-down.d.ts(19,29): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'ui/list-picker'

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your project tsconfig.json file:

```
"paths": {
        "*": [
            "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
            "./node_modules/*",
            "src/*"
        ]
 }
```